# Is it appropriate to ask about experiences with specific extensions and help customizing?

Tags: discussion

After looking at every multi-warehouse,  inventory and shipping extension, I can find, I have settled on one closest to my needs. The cost is reasonable to my customer.

I looked at taking the time to develop the needed functionality and it is beyond my current abilities.

I am not sure many in the  Magento Community need multi-warehouse functionality, my other customers don't need to manage several locations.

The developers have dropped customizing and conflict resolution and are focusing on developing the extensions, just this month Oct 18. It is guaranteed to work on standard Magento install, so that's where I'd have to start.

**So My Question:**

Is it OK to ask about this extension, about the experiences developers have had or about getting help customizing?

Also helpful would be extensions that are know to work with this one.

If it helps the discussion I will give the name of the Company and extension.

*[Moderator edit: the question in question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9945/what-is-your-experiences-with-using-and-or-modifying-multi-warehouse-by-innoexts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9945/what-is-your-experiences-with-using-and-or-modifying-multi-warehouse-by-innoexts)*

Comment: I really wrestled with this, knowing that I would ruffle some feathers. I would like to know who makes good extensions and who to avoid. Not everyone knows this, especially the new folks who are new to everything even asking questions. I can see why that is avoided, who would want to moderate that? But it would be handy. I saw an extension list and several of the extensions I checked out and the were only adverts for a custom shop. I even tried to contact the developer googled and found them and they never returned the call or emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say yes. It's clear from your post here that the intent is genuine.

Comment: The answer I was wanting, just wanted to check the protocol.

Comment: My question was deleted.  Cannot find it now.

Comment: Undeleted. Need to have a pow-wow with fellow moderators as we seem to have a healthy difference of opinion :-)

Comment: Clarity is good. Thanks to all the moderators for taking time to provide guidelines and insight to others.

Answer (score 0):

How to make sure that you are not affiliated with the extension vendor and not just promoting it? Unless you are a known member of a community there is no way. This is not a discrimination. I'm just trying to protect this (website) act of good will from the exploits who are trying to use it to push their stuff.

It's not an answer but in fact it is.

Comment: I agree that un-disclosed affiliation need to be avoided. I am not affiliated with this company. I actually am not sure I made the correct call buying the software. They changed the support policy and dropped any customizing and conflict resolution. So not very shining recommendations. But I do not have the experience to build the things I found in the software.  So This is why I asked first on meta. I changed my question a little but the fact is that I have this extension and want to customize it. I'd build it from scratch but I don't have the expectancy. I'm looking for the big pieces first.

Comment: I would build it from scratch but I don't have the experience or time.